# A more sophisticated method of finding all $n$ satisfying $n! = (k + 1)(k-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> Find all $n$ such that $n!$ can be expressed in the form $(k+1)(k-1)$ where $k$ is an integer $>1$.

This problem stems from another problem that I tried to solve from David Burton's number theory book. The problem is as follows (verbatim):

> Find the values of $n \leq 7$ for which $n! + 1$ is a perfect square (it is unknown whether $n! + 1$ is a square for any $n > 7$)

I decided to convert this into the first problem. However the method I used to solve it was trial and error. I can't think of any sophisticated method, although I'm sure there is one. Furthermore this problem is in the chapter discussing induction, however I have no idea how induction could be used in this problem, seeing as this is not a proof problem (unless the parentheses invites further proof that the statement does not hold for $n > 7$). Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S Although the problem only requires $n \leq 7$ I am interested to know what happens for a general case.

Comment: If it's unknown (i.e. a "well-known" unsolved problem), how do you expect us to solve it?

Comment: why do you think the rephrasing will help?  the two phrasings are trivially equivalent.

Comment: @RobertIsrael hmm, I didn't think that's what it meant, sorry for the trouble. I just thought that it urged the reader to further try proving it.

Comment: @lulu I thought it might be easier to handle in that form. I lack experience in solving problems, so it's probably not the way to go...